# Unable to remove a CALayer from UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

So, I have this custom `UITextField` and I have two methods to add `CALayer` and remove the `CALayer` but remove is not working.

```
@IBDesignable class AppTextField : UITextField {

    private let bottomLine = CALayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        self.addBottomLine()
        self.clearButtonMode = .unlessEditing
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    func removeBttomLine() {
        bottomLine.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    private func addBottomLine() {
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height + 4), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: 1))
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#DCCFCA")?.cgColor
        self.borderStyle = .none
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `removeBttomLine()`?

Comment: @DonMag in my `viewController`.

Comment: Are you showing the red line at the start? Then removing it when the field becomes first responder? Or NOT showing it *until* it becomes first responder?

Comment: @DonMag I'm not sure! I'm trying to remove it from the `ViewDidLoad` of my `ViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you should do in `layoutSubviews()` is update frames as necessary.

This will show the red line when the field is ***NOT*** being edited, and will remove it while the field **IS** being edited:

```
@IBDesignable class AppTextField : UITextField {

    private let bottomLine = CALayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.clearButtonMode = .unlessEditing
        self.borderStyle = .none
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        addBottomLine()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        var r = bounds
        r.origin.y = bounds.maxY
        r.size.height = 4.0
        bottomLine.frame = r
    }

    func removeBottomLine() {
        bottomLine.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    private func addBottomLine() {
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        super.resignFirstResponder()
        addBottomLine()
        return true
    }
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        super.becomeFirstResponder()
        removeBottomLine()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason could because the `layoutSubviews` method gets called multiple times and the layer is getting added multiple times. Try moving the `addBottomLine` method to `required init?(coder:)` method if you're using storyboard or use `init(frame:)` or custom `init` whichever gets called just once. Here's an example:

```
@IBDesignable class AppTextField : UITextField {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        addBottomLine()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing 3 things in your add method:

1. adusting frame
2. setting color
3. adding as sublayer

And because you're calling it from `layoutSubviews` it's called multiple times and you're ending with multiple layers added and that's why calling remove doesn't seem to work.
To make this code work you should move adding part to init (`withCoder`, `withFrame` or both). You can join it with setting color because it can be done once. Next part is adjusting frame in `layoutSubviews` which is required because layers can't into autolayout. At the end you will have creation, adding as sublayer and set part called once at init, and adjusting called multiple times on layout pass. Now remove when called once - it would work with visible effect this time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!